# How to sync up git master, origin/master & upstream master

Tags: git, github

[image: This photo]

The above photo shows where master and its 2 remote tracking branches are now. There is no code change difference between remotes/upstream/master and the other 2 branches.  How do I get them back pointing to the same commit?

I got in this situation by pushing a number of commits to origin and then creating a PR and merging & squashing those commits on upstream. Then I did:

```
[master]git fetch upstream master
[master]git merge upstream/master
[master]git push origin master
```

Besides getting these back in sync, can someone tell me how not to get in this situation in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be done with:

```
git push upstream master
```

So that you move upstream/master to the same revision where local master is.

Comment: Thanks! If I had tried just experimenting myself, I'm sure the solution wouldn't have been so simple.